# Grass 7 - where is r.regression.multi hiding?

Tags: grass-gis, statistics

I compiled Grass 7 on Ubuntu and all works fine - except, I cannot find r.regression.multi. I installed it, yet it is nowhere to be found in the drop-down menus; r.regression.line is there and works, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is (yet) an Addon and not in the main source code package:

http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/AddOns/GRASS7/raster#r.regression.multi

Installation:

- either "g.extension r.regression.multi"
- or wxGUI menu -> Settings -> Addons extensions -> Install

Comment: Thank you, Markus. I did this (via wxGUI menu and install), yet I cannot find it. It should be in the main Grass menu, or do I have to start the extension from terminal?

Comment: Mhh, I thought it would be auto-added to the menu. Please check the command console (second tab at bottom) and type the command name therein, it should pop up!

Comment: Markus, thank you again. It works now with the command line!

Comment: Update: it is now available in GRASS 7 main (hence no longer an Addon but shipped with core GRASS 7): http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.regression.multi.html